# How to Configure Blazor Hub Mapping in ASP.NET Core MVC App

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an existing MVC application in which I wish to use blazor for some specific requirement. After integrating it,I realized that on the index page of the app, the razor components work just fine without problems. But when I move to another page, it will lose the blazor hub connection. I noticed it might a mapping problem because on the homepage, `[appurl]/_blazor` works and connects just fine. But when I go to another page, `[appurl]/[controller]/_blazor` tries to connect but it throws 404.
How can I get it to work for all routes on the application?

Answer (score 4):

Based on your Information, i would guess that you are missing the base-tag, or you aren`t mapping the BlazorHub.
If you want, that for example Blazor handles all URLs under /app/*, and the others get handled by MVC, then your Endpoints need to be configured like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/app/{*page}", "/_Host");
            });
```

In your `_Host.cshtml` you then have to add
`<base href="/app" />`

Without the `endpoints.MapBlazorHub();` your Components will get rendered, but you won`t have a connection to Blazor-Server, and without `<base href="/app" />` the Browser will perform a full Page reload, instead of using Blazor to navigate to the new Page.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution but it didn't work. I noticed in examples  of this sort, there was no `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage()` line of code there. I think it only applies to full blazor apps.

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha Did you find solution to this? I have same issue right now, where `_blazor/initializers` can't be found as it tries to look for it in the current path. base-tag is not an option for me as with that, anchors and tabs have wrong URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation, ASP.NET Razor pages web application and added Blazor pages, we build Administration part of application with Blazor and Blazor pages are in Areas/Admin directory.
Problem with routing is solved by modifing @Page directive in blazor _Host.cshtml file, there you can set routing for blazor pages with @Page [custom routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes) like this:

> @page "/admin/{*page}"